# Triggering a CI/CD build when a tag is added to the GitHub repo this repo is forked from?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-release

There's a project using GitHub releases to release their packages.  I've built a process that repackages the released files and uploads the repackaged files to a special GitHub release in my fork of the repository.

I'd like to fully automate this by having my process run automatically whenever a new GitHub release tag is added to the original repository.

Is there an existing CI/CD service that could do this?

- If yes which and can you point me to the right area of the docs to figure it out?
- If no, are there options for wiring this up myself somehow?  For example, using a webhook and an existing service in a non-standard way to accomplish the goal?

Comment: The repo owner would have to set up a webhook to deliver some service you could subscribe to. Unfortunately the only option would be to poll the API for a new release.

Comment: I feared as much, @osowskit, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score -1):

> I'd like to fully automate this by having my process run automatically whenever a new GitHub **release tag is added** to the original repository.

GitHub has webhooks for this purpose.

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#createevent

> **CreateEvent**
>   Represents a created repository, branch, or **tag**.
>
> *Note:* webhooks will not receive this event for created repositories. Additionally, webhooks will not receive this event for tags **if more than three tags are pushed at once**.

Once the tag is pushed GitHub will invoke the given URL with the appropriate JSON as described in the DOCs above.

Comment: Yeah, I read the webhook docs, and to my reading that would only trigger for a creation of a tag in *this* repository, not the repository it was *forked from*.  Do you know otherwise?